# FindBugs error on Sonar4.3

Tags: findbugs, sonarqube

Using gradle sonarRunner (v1.12) task on Sonar's server v4.3, the following error is launched :

```
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
> org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to install plugin: DefaultPluginMetadata[key=findbugs,version=2.2.1]
```

Linked to last plugin update for Sonar.
(same issue with maven 3.2.10).
Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
   Fail to install plugin: DefaultPluginMetadata[key=findbugs,version=2.2.1]: No locks available -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3:sonar (default-cli) on project alarm-manager-parent_9.x.x.x.x-SNAPSHOT: Fail to install plugin: DefaultPluginMetadata[key=findbugs,version=2.2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to install plugin: DefaultPluginMetadata[key=findbugs,version=2.2.1]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to install plugin: DefaultPluginMetadata[key=findbugs,version=2.2.1]
    at org.sonar.core.plugins.PluginJarInstaller.install(PluginJarInstaller.java:42)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginJarInstaller.installToCache(BatchPluginJarInstaller.java:40)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginRepository.doStart(BatchPluginRepository.java:81)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginRepository.start(BatchPluginRepository.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:132)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No locks available
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:832)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.lock(FileChannel.java:860)
    at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.unzip(FileCache.java:192)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginJarInstaller.extractPluginDependencies(BatchPluginJarInstaller.java:46)
    at org.sonar.core.plugins.PluginJarInstaller.copyDependencies(PluginJarInstaller.java:49)
    at org.sonar.core.plugins.PluginJarInstaller.install(PluginJarInstaller.java:40)
    ... 55 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Could you relaunch a Maven analysis with the option "-e", this will help to get the root cause. Thanks

Comment: I' ve updated the stacktrace following "mvn -e" instruction.

Comment: Are you executing SonarQube analysis on special file system ?

Comment: df -T show it's an 'ext4' partition on a /dev/sda4 filesystem (in a Red Hat 6 cluster).

Comment: Here is what we should try to figure out : why the SonarQube Java process doesn't manage to get a lock on this findbugs plugin/file ? But unhappily I don't have any idea for the time being :(

Comment: Thanks anyway Freddy: that's weird because the error has came up after the java plugin's upgrade. Could it be a conflict with another plugin or java version ?

Comment: Could you provide the list of plugins/jars located in your extensions/plugins directory ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem. So I figured out the way Sonar runs, but could not resolve the problem. I only had a workaround.

- Client, connects to Sonar Server and downloads plugins (findbugs, PMD, jacoco, etc) to USER_HOME/.sonar/cache directory
- For every cached file (for instance : sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.2.1.jar in your scenario), jar files within their META-INF/lib folder are extracted to [filename + "_unzip"] folder. Before extracting, it locks a file named [filename + "_unzip.lock"]
  You can see the code related to this part [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-home/src/main/java/org/sonar/home/cache/FileCache.java)
  In your scenario, it tries to cerate a folder [sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.2.1.jar_unzip] and a lock file [sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.2.1.jar_unzip.lock] in the same level of [sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.2.1.jar] file.
- As of now, I do not know the reason but it can not lock the file, and throws exception.

As a workaround, I uploaded all unzipped files from my local environment to the server, and it worked. I will deep dive later for the right solution